# looping through elements sub-elements

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I am trying to extract data from a structure that looks like 
http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm?state=8T

using the following function I am trying to loop through every product tag

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($resp);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('ns2', 'http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd');
$xpath->registerNamespace('a', 'http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01');

foreach($xpath->query('//a:Product') as $product){
    echo $product->query('//ns2:ItemAttributes/ns2:Author')->item(0)->nodeValue
}
```

I now realize that this is the wrong way to extract data from within the for loop, but what is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
foreach($xpath->query('//a:Product') as $product){
    echo $xpath->query('.//ns2:ItemAttributes/ns2:Author', $product)->item(0)->textContent
}
```

Comment: I wish I could of tried it out before, but I just went the cheap and dirty way by using str_replace() to replace all the namespaces. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you need specific tags, you can do:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($resp);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("Product") as $product){
    echo $product->getElementsByTagName("Author")->item(0)->nodeValue."<br />";
}
```

Otherwise (if you need the whole data) there are community-made solutions for converting the whole XML into a simple array/object.